Limit number of conversations under Direct messages
It seems that after a recent update, Slack no longer limits the number of conversations under the 'Direct messages' section of the Home tab.
N.B: I am not referring to the DMs tab in the navigation bar, but the 'Direct messages' section in the Home tab.
Slack used to automatically clear older conversations, so that a smaller number of more recent conversations were kept around. That behavior seems to have changed within the last few months. I would like to restore it. Is there any way to do this?
This is essentially the inverse of Why does Slack limit the number of contacts in my sidebar's direct messages section? - I'd like to restore this behavior

I opened Slack today and noticed that my number of DMs was much smaller than normal. Maybe this has been resolved and they are now limiting themselves again?
